# Appending object to a dictionary by key is replicating over the whole dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I have been trying to create a dictionary consisting of pairs of keys and an array of tuples. Each "instrument" within the "subportfolio" would be one of such tuples, and my idea is to populate a dictionary based on one of the tuple fields containing the key for the dictionary. The code below shows my current implementation:

```
def assetClassBreakdown(subclasses, subportfolio):
    instrumentsDictionary = dict.fromkeys(subclasses, [])

    for instrument in subportfolio:
        # The subclass is in the ninth index within the instrument
        instrumentsDictionary[instrument[8]].append(instrument)

    return instrumentsDictionary
```

The problem is that every time I append a tuple based on the key (instrument[8]), it is appending this tuple to every key inside the dictionary. Basiclly, for every key I end up with exactly the same array of tuples.

Comment: You'd be better off with `instrumentsDictionary = defaultdict(list)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe if you could please point me to the original question I would be very grateful.

Comment: There is literally a link in the header of this page.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you beautiful man